# ¿Cómo evitar que los items de carrito se muevan al cambiar la cantidad? - Darryldecode Cart

Tags: laravel

Estoy usando el paquete Darryldecode Cart, y cuando ingreso al carrito y modifico la cantidad de un producto se mueve hacía el final del la lista, pareciera que los ordena de manera descendiente por fecha de actualización, y no sé como modificarlo para que no los ordene y queden en la misma posición que estaban.